# PHP If referrer exists show div... How?

Tags: php, if-statement, referrer

I would like to show a div table with the referrer title, but only when the referrer exists, if it doesn't exist - don't show it. I need to put an "if exists" condition after function. I'm a beginner. So far I have this function:

```
function getSiteTitle(){
$RefURL = (is_null($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? 'Un know' : $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if($RefURL != 'Un know'){
    $con = file_get_contents($RefURL) or die (" can't open URL referer ");
    $pattern = "/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i";
    preg_match($pattern,$con,$match);
    $result = array($match[1],$RefURL);
    return $result;
   }
   else{
      return false;
   }
}
$info = getSiteTitle();
echo "". $info[0];
```

I want to show some DIV table with referrer title but when referrer exists. If not exists don't show DIV.

Comment: `if(isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { 'HTTP referer exists' }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$info = getSiteTitle();
if ($info !== false) {
   echo "<div>Ref title: {$info[0]}</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `empty()` to check refer exist or not

```
function getSiteTitle(){
$RefURL = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '');
  if(!empty($RefURL)){
   $con = file_get_contents($RefURL) or die (" can't open URL referer ");
   $pattern = "/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i";
   preg_match($pattern,$con,$match);
   $result = array($match[1],$RefURL);
   return $result;
  }
  else{
   return false;
  }
}


$info = getSiteTitle();
if ($info != false) {
   echo "<div>Ref:". $info[0]."</div>";
}
```